# Liferay web applications deployment dependencies

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have a liferay application on Liferay 6.2 EE. I know that we can give the deployment dependencies via `required-deployment-contexts` property inside `liferay-plugin-package.properties`.

My problem is that I want my liferay hook to be deployed only after liferay portal web app (ROOT) is deployed. I tried giving

1. `required-deployment-contexts=ROOT`
2. `required-deployment-contexts=/`

but it does not work.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I don't really understand. Hooks are meant to override or extend portal. It doesn't make sense to me if they are deployed before ROOT. required-deployment-context are useful if you need some service, for example, provided by another plugin. What are the symptoms? Why isn't it working, or what are you missing?

Comment: What hooks deploy or change is "overridden" in ROOT, so hooks are absolutely deployed after root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your web application might be deployed to your appserver before Liferay itself, the portlet and hook portions of your web applications never will be deployed before Liferay. There's a two-stage deployment process going on: Liferay will inspect which web applications are available and check if they need to be processed - e.g. if they are Liferay plugins or just plain web applications.

The file name `liferay-plugin-package.properties` gives a hint as to who is processing it: Liferay does. And it will *naturally* only do so once it's been deployed.

Now if you want to deploy even the web application part of your plugin - not just the Liferay hook - after Liferay: That's a function of the appserver you're using. And naturally your appserver couldn't care less about a descriptor named `liferay-plugin-package.properties`. The only scenario that I can see for such a demand is when you want to rely on Liferay being available when the webapp is initializing - but you shouldn't do this, because at that time, Liferay does not yet know about your hook.

Comment: Sir Olaf kock I want to hit webdav url but it is asking credentials.
We are using ntlm n it is working fine but for webdav url it is asking credentials. Do we have any way to avoid credentials prompt for webdav url please.